# When light is reflected, if some of the light is absorbed in the particle, does it change the particle?

Tags: visible-light, atoms, absorption, photon-emission

Which color/frequency of the light is absorbed and which part is reflected? How is it determined which part will be absorbed? Does that depend on the particle?

N.B: When I say particle, please keep in mind that I am not formally educated in very much science or math, so let's say that the particle is one single atom like hydrogen.

Answer (score 1):

When coming down to single atoms one is in the particle domain, the quantum mechanical frame, and in this domain light is composed of zillions of photons. As photons impinge on a [hydrogen atom](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hydcn.html) there are several things that may happen:

a) A photon of the exact energy for an energy level of the hydrogen atom will raise the electron to a higher level and be completely absorbed. This will deplete the number of photons in the beam and that particular frequency ( as energy=h*frequency) will be less in the balance of light by the number of absorbed photons. ( the electron will fall back and release a photon but that will be in a random theta phi direction , a very small part of the photons will join back the light beam.

b) A photon can kick out completely the electron if its energy is large enough, and the atom will ionize and again there will be an eventual capture of an electron and a random direction photon.

The above two change the color balance of the reflected/deflected beam.

c) A third possibility is elastic scatter of the photon, then the beam will just be deflected  and keep its spectrum of frequencies content.

It depends on the atoms  which frequencies will take part in a) and b)

Comment: At 47 years old and with nothing more than one undergraduate class in physical science I understand the philosophy of the particles to which you infer however I do not have the vocabulary to discuss it intelligently at this moment. So bear with me please. What word is utilized to indicate the "size" of a photon or electron or as you say an theta phi? I do not mean weight, and I do not mean volume. and I am confused by the word gravity,  but am I correctly understanding gravity is basically the electromagnetic force of matter?

Comment: Gravity is one of the four fundamental forces,  the hope of theorists is that at very high energies all four forces http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/forces/funfor.html will be described within one mathematical model, but this is still a dream. They are all distinct in the interactions of elementary particles https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle which are point particles, i.e. sitting at one (x,y,z) mass and all quantum numbers. Quantum mechanics is necessary to describe them.